# How can I automatically set start date to multiple sequential summary tasks based on the resource allocation?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to use VBA to automatically set the start date of multiple sequential summary tasks (that has no predecessors) based on the resources availability of my project.

The intention is to optimize the duration of the project, without overalocate an resource.

I wrote the following code, but it is not perfect yet.

```
Sub Test01()

Dim t As Task
Dim ts As Tasks
Dim r As Resource
Dim rs As Resources
Dim rOver As Integer 'Sum of Overallocated Resources
Dim hoje As Date

Set ts = ActiveProject.Tasks
Set rs = ActiveProject.Resources


For Each t In ts
rOver = 1
hoje = Date

        If t.Summary Then
            If t.Predecessors = "" Then
                Do While rOver > 0
                    t.Start = hoje
                        For Each r In rs
                            If r.Overallocated Then
                            rOver = rOver + 1
                            Else
                            rOver = 0
                            End If
                        Next r
                    hoje = hoje + 1
                    t.Start = hoje
                Loop
            Else
                t.Manual = False
            End If
        Else
            t.Manual = False
            
        End If
Next t


End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this challenge?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not use the built-in tools to do this? See [Distribute project work evenly (level resource assignments)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/distribute-project-work-evenly-level-resource-assignments-59ee715d-4446-42c9-8756-4ea2a5a7e4a0).